# nuxt.js cant send props and get data with emits

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have 3 components. and i wanna data transfering between these components. but i cant be handle it. 3 COMPONENTS = MAIN - INPUT - CREDITCARD. how can i handle it using props and emits? I think i have to use v-model but im not sure.

```
---MAIN COMPONENT
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <Input type="text" id="cardnumber" labelText="CVV *" />
        {{ card.cvv }}
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <CreditCard :cvv="card.cvv" />
    </div>

    </div>
</template>
```

MY Input component

```html
<input :type="type" :id="id"
        class="border border-smoke text-gray-900 text-sm rounded focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
        :placeholder="placeholder" :pattern="pattern" required="required" />
```

and Credit Card.vue

```html
<div>
    <p class="text-graphene font-bold">{{cvv}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: please fix the divs, there are more closing tags than opening tags

Comment: Also, it's not sure  what the `text`, `id`, `labelText` props are doing in your `Input` component. Please add more code regarding that so we can see the full picture of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

`Input` will consider as a form element not a custom component. What I understand is that you want to pass `cvv` number from the input field to `CreditCard` component. If Yes, Here you go **:**

```js
Vue.component('creditcard', {
  props: ['cvv'],
  template: `<div>
                <p>{{ cvv }}</p>
            </div>`
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
        card: {
        cvv: 404
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <Input type="text" id="cardnumber" labelText="CVV *" v-model="card.cvv" />
  <CreditCard :cvv="card.cvv"></CreditCard>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rohit. input is a custom component. not form element. but html form element <input> is inside of input component

Comment: @yigitden In that case you can emit the value from input to parent and then pass in `CreditCard` component.